# can't update table loop in mysql

Tags: php

i have loop table contains text area and there is 7 rows as result from loop when press submit the last row relative from loop only that i can updated it

```
            $id = $_SESSION['id'];
            $sql = "select * from sp where team_id ='$id' "; 
            $result = $connt->query($sql);

            if($result->num_rows > 0 ){
            ?>
            <?php
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 
        ?>
<form action="update.php" method="post">
        <tr>
    <td> <?php echo $row['name']; ?> </td>
    <td><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?> "> <?php echo $row['id']; ?> </td>
    <td> <textarea name="sun"> <?php echo $row['sunday']; ?> </textarea></td> 
    <td> <textarea name="mon"> <?php echo $row['monday']; ?> </textarea></td> 
    <td> <textarea name="tues" > <?php echo $row['tuesday']; ?> </textarea></td> 
    <td> <textarea name="wednes" > <?php echo $row['wednesday']; ?></textarea></td> 
</tr>
    <?php
    }
    }
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" >
</form>
```

file update.php

```
  include'../../../config/connect.php';

     $sun = $_POST['sun'];
$mon = $_POST['mon'];
$tues = $_POST['tues'];
$wednes = $_POST['wednes'];
$thurs = $_POST['thurs'];
$fri = $_POST['fri'];
$satur = $_POST['satur'];

$id = $_POST['id'];

if($_POST['submit']){
$sql = "UPDATE sp SET sunday='$sun', monday='$mon', tuesday='$tues', 
wednesday='$wednes', thursday='$thurs', friday='$fri', saturday='$satur' 
WHERE id='$id' ";
};

if ($connt->query($sql) === true){
?>


<?php
}else{


echo 'notdone';

}
```

the last row in loop is only effected cause the last row attribute overwrite the others

Comment: Question is not clear

Comment: None of this code looks related to updating a table

Answer (score 2):

You are not closing the forms properly, you should save the id in a hidden field so you can use it in the update query

```
 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 
        ?>
<form action="update.php" method="post">
        <tr>
    <td> <?php echo $row['name']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $row['id']; ?> <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?> "></td>
    <td> <textarea name="sun"> <?php echo $row['sunday']; ?> </textarea></td> 
    <td> <textarea name="mon"> <?php echo $row['monday']; ?> </textarea></td> 
    <td> <textarea name="tues" > <?php echo $row['tuesday']; ?> </textarea></td> 
    <td> <textarea name="wednes" > <?php echo $row['wednesday']; ?></textarea></td> 
</tr>
<input type="submit" name="submit" >
</form>
    <?php
    }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find my form design here. Kindly use  and submit action after while loop or else it will run for all the rows Which is actually wrong.

There is no update query in your code. Please write the code and let me answer after that.

```
<form action="update.php" method="post">
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<?php 
 $id = $_SESSION['id'];
 $sql = "select * from sp where team_id ='$id' "; 
 $result = $connt->query($sql);

  if($result->num_rows > 0 ){
 ?>
 <?php
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 
 ?>
        <tr>
    <td> <?php echo $row['name']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $row['id']; ?> <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?> "></td>
    <td> <textarea name="sun"> <?php echo $row['sunday']; ?> </textarea></td> 
    <td> <textarea name="mon"> <?php echo $row['monday']; ?> </textarea></td> 
    <td> <textarea name="tues" > <?php echo $row['tuesday']; ?> </textarea></td> 
    <td> <textarea name="wednes" > <?php echo $row['wednesday']; ?></textarea></td> 
</tr>

    <?php
    }
    }
?>
<tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" ></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: here is the problem . for example the result contain 7 rows the data relative from loop. when updated text area for example first row only it give me the last row retrieved from loop cause it's override the name attribute and id form

Comment: Ofcourse it will override because u didn't declare the field name as array. So it will take the last row value and override everything.

Comment: Declare the field name as array like sun[],mon[].. And get the value using $_POST['sun']. use foreach loop to update each and every row in the table.